Trying to pull data from another tab where one column equals specific text and the entry is between a date range
I have a sheet of client transactions.  From this tab I want to pull transactions marked as "Payment" but I want to be able to pull them month by month, so for example, this month, I only pull transactions for March 2024. Having some trouble parsing the formula correctly and not returning an error.
I tried to piece this formula together from different tutorials:
=query(TRANSACTIONS!B6:P9997, "select B,C,G where O='Payment'" and  B >= DATE '"&TEXT(2024-03-01")&"' and B <= DATE '"&TEXT(2024-04-01")&"'")
Just returns an error.  I'm sure its not formulated correctly.


You may try:
=query(TRANSACTIONS!B6:P, "select B,C,G where O='Payment' and B >= date '"&to_text("2024-03-01")&"' AND B < date '"&to_text("2024-04-01")&"'")

OR this to pull previous month data automatically:
=filter(choosecols(TRANSACTIONS!B6:P,1,2,6),TRANSACTIONS!O6:O="Payment",eomonth(TRANSACTIONS!B6:B,)=eomonth(now(),-1))


Thank you! This works perfectly! Appreciate the help.

Review your quotation marks and apostrophes as those don't look like they are matching up the way I would ever expect in a formula.
